# CSS animated typing

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying make an animation as if I was typing. To achieve this I'm using CSS animation 'steps'.

The animation itself works just fine. However, if I want to animate multiple lines of text, they all start playing at the same time. Which isn't giving me the desired effect. *(Tried using `<br>` in a single `<h1>`, which cut off the text, but again started the animations simultaneously.)*

To counter this, I put the next line of text in an `<h2>` and set an animation-delay for every line of text. Which works, but the text is visible before the animation starts.

I want the text to be hidden until the animation starts playing, to really get that 'live typing' effect.

Anyone got any ideas on how I can achieve this?

HTML

```
<div class="content"> 
    <h1>Hi there! My name is Jeff.</h1>
    <h2>And I create cool stuff.</h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content h1 {
    background:white;
    opacity:0.7;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-right: 3px solid black;
    -webkit-animation: typing 2s steps(26, end), 
                        blink-caret 1s step-end 2s;
}
.content h2 {
    background:white;
    opacity:0.7;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-right: 3px solid black;
    -webkit-animation: typing 2s steps(26, end), 
                        blink-caret 1s step-end infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay:3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes typing {
    from { width: 0; }
    to { width:400px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink-caret {
    from, to { border-color: transparent }
    50% { border-color: black }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E3uD3/)

Comment: Well you have to set the initial width for `.content h2` to `0` of course …

Comment: That did somewhat work. However, once the animation is done playing, the h2 shoots back to width:0px. Any idea how I might counter act that?

Comment: Also, it doesn't completely hide it. The border-right is still visible.

Comment: `animation-fill-mode:forwards` fixes the width getting back to 0.

Comment: Thanks! That brought me one step closer. Appreciate it.

Comment: Got it. The padding was still showing.

Comment: Great Tutorial: https://youtu.be/4Mxv8KcAdLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add:

```
animation-fill-mode:both;
```

to your `h2` (with the necessary prefixes). That way, you aren't setting it to a zero width outside of your animation, so browsers that don't support this CSS will display the heading (which I guess is what you're after). See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/qs7rL/).

The [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation-fill-mode):

> specifies how a CSS animation should apply styles to its target before
>   and after it is executing

Setting it to `both` in this instance means that your `h2` will have a width of `0` *before* it starts executing, and a width of `400px` after.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments already include a solution, perhaps this might be another way of doing it - by using timeouts and setting `visibility: hidden` at the beginning (For simplification I just used jQuery to set the visiblitiy).

Include the following CSS rule:

```
.content {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

As JavaScript you would have:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('#contentdiv h1').css('visibility', 'visible');
}, 100);

window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('#contentdiv h2').css('visibility', 'visible');
}, 3100);
```

See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E3uD3/1/)

Comment: This works very good aswell. However, I should have specified I'd rather not use any jQuery/JavaScript. Thanks for the help though. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```css
p
{
  font:500 22px consolas;    
  width:20ch;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  animation:type 5s steps(20) infinite;
}
@keyframes type
{
  0%{ width:0; } 
}
```

```html
<p>Text Type Animation</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the OP's question, but in case someone else finds this useful:

I wanted to be able to typing-animate a *pararaph* of text, a single `<p>` tag which might contain text that would wrap, and produce an unknown number of actual lines.   Applying a simple linear animation to the `p` tag itself wouldn't work, so instead, I took the approach of having several "hider" elements that would cover the paragraph of text, each one line high, and then I would animate each of those so they would shrink away, reveal characters from the line of text beneath them.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
<!-- container div is required to set absolute positions within it, so that .typing and .hiders exactly overlap -->

  <p class="typing">
    This paragraph of text will be animated 
    with a "typewriter" style effect, and it 
    will continue to work even if it splits across 
    multiple lines.  Well, in this case, up to a 
    maximum of 5 lines, but you get the picture.
  </p>

  <div class="hiders">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

You need a container, and position the `.typing` element and the `.hiders` using `absolute` so that they're on top of each other:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;  
}
.typing {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.hiders {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

And the animation gets applied to each `p` inside the `.hiders`:

```
.hiders p {
  position: relative; 
  clear: both; 
  margin: 0;
  float: right; /* makes animation go left-to-right */
  width:0; /* graceful degradation: if animation doesn't work, these are invisible by default */
  background: white; /* same as page background */
  animation: typing 2s steps(30, end);
  animation-fill-mode: both;  /* load first keyframe on page load, leave on last frame at end */
}

.hiders p:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.hiders p:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
  /* etc */
```

Here's the final fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/hjwp/514cLzxn/

Original credit for inspiration: [Lea Verou](http://lea.verou.me/2011/09/pure-css3-typing-animation-with-steps/)

Comment: I saw this on her site too...I wanted to point out that this did not work for me at all and does not work on codepen....just looks like this:http://puu.sh/o396q/f7610b8da4.png