# CSS Typing Effect

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a typing effect with multiple lines in CSS.

This was a good reference point I followed:

[CSS animated typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925283/css-animated-typing)

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/

Now my desired effect is that the first border-right's visibility be hidden once the first blinking cursor's animation ends. A the border-right is still on screen after the animation ends and I want it not to be visible. (As if enter button on a keyboard was pressed.) How would I go about that?

https://jsfiddle.net/6567onn8/5/

```css
.typewriter h1 {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 100%;
  border-right: .15em solid #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* keeps content in one line */
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  animation: typing 2.5s steps(22, end), blink-caret .75s step-end;
}
.typewriter h2 {
  font-size: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid black;
  -webkit-animation: typing 2s steps(26, end), blink-caret 1s step-end infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation: typing 2s steps(26, end), blink-caret 1s step-end infinite;
  -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
}
/* The typing effect */

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 9em;
  }
}
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: #000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
  <h1>Hi. I'm Andy.</h1>
  <h2>I love learning.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean https://jsfiddle.net/6567onn8/5/ ?

Comment: @GCyrillus woow, CSS typing, that's pretty awesome ! `:-D`

Comment: Great Tutorial: https://youtu.be/4Mxv8KcAdLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take out `infinite`

```css
.typewriter h1 {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 100%;
  border-right: .15em solid #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* keeps content in one line */
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  animation: typing 2.5s steps(22, end), blink-caret .75s step-end;
}
.typewriter h2 {
  font-size: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid black;
  -webkit-animation: typing 2s steps(26, end), blink-caret 1s step-end;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation: typing 2s steps(26, end), blink-caret 1s step-end;
  -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
}
/* The typing effect */

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 9em;
  }
}
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: #000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
  <h1>Hi. I'm Andy.</h1>
  <h2>I love learning.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: The border is still visible in the viewport, removing infinite pushes the border to the edge of the viewport

Comment: I got it you made look at the code a little closer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}
.blackboard-wrapper {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,#26180B 70%,#362418 77%,#77736A 78%,#655444 78%);
}
.black-board {
 height: 360px;
 width: 800px;
 transform: translateY(70px);
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,#000000 77%,#111111 78%,#222222 77%,#000000 78%);
 border-width: 15px;
 border-style: groove;
 border-color: #2E1E11;
 position: relative;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.date {
 position: absolute;
 left: 15px;
 top: 10px;
}
.date > span {
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.black-board::before {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 content: "";
 right: 0;
 background-color: #afafaf;
 height: 2px;
 top: 94px;
}
.topic {
 position: absolute;
 top: 28px;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 text-decoration: underline;
 word-spacing: 8px;
}
.writing {
 position: absolute;
 top: 120px;
 left: 15px;
 right: 15px;
 bottom: 15px;
}
.writing::after,
.writing::before {
 position: absolute;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-size: 30px;
 animation-name: write;
 animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.7,.45,.97,.36);
}
.writing::before{
 font-size: 25px;
 content:"This is cool NAAA???";
 top: 70px;
 color: #1FBEA6;
 animation-name: write2;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.7,.45,.97,.36);
}
@keyframes write{
 0%{content:"";}
 3%{content:"V_";}
 6%{content:"VI_";}
 9%{content:"VIK_";}
 12%{content:"VIKA_";}
 15%,25%{content:"VIKAS";}
 28%{content:"VIKA_";}
 31%{content:"VIK_";}
 34%{content:"VI_";}
 37%{content:"V_";}
 40%,50%{content:"";}
 53%{content:"P_";}
 56%{content:"PA_";}
 59%{content:"PAT_";}
 62%{content:"PATE_";}
 65%,75%{content:"PATEL";}
 78%{content:"PATE_";}
 81%{content:"PAT_";}
 84%{content:"PA_";}
 88%{content:"P_";}
 91%,100%{content:"";}
}

@keyframes write2{
 0%{content:"";}
 5%{content:"T_";}
 10%{content:"Th_";}
 15%{content:"Thi_";}
 20%{content:"This_ ";}
 25%{content:"This i_";}
 30%{content:"This is_";}
 35%{content:"This is_ ";}
 40%{content:"This is c_";}
 45%{content:"This is co_";}
 50%{content:"This is coo_";}
 55%{content:"This is cool_";}
 65%{content:"This is cool N_";}
 70%{content:"This is cool NA_";}
 75%{content:"This is cool NAA_";}
 80%{content:"This is cool NAAA";}
 85%{content:"This is cool NAAA?";}
 90%{content:"This is cool NAAA??";}
 95%{content:"This is cool NAAA???";}
 100%{content:"This is cool NAAA???";}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet"> 
<div class="blackboard-wrapper">
  <div class="black-board">
   <div class="date">
    <span>DATE</span>
    <span>25|oct|2018</span>
   </div>
   <div class="topic">TYPING EFFECT USING CSS</div>
   <div class="writing"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

https://codepen.io/Vikaspatel/pen/mzarrO

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  /*This part is important for centering*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.typing-demo {
  width: 22ch;
  animation: typing 2s steps(22), blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 3px solid;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2em;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
}
    
@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="typing-demo">
      This is a typing demo.
    </div>
</div>
```

Easiest way of doing it in CSS.